# PyQt: Creating simple men with images

Tags: user-interface, focus, pyqt4, imagebutton, qlabel

I'm creating a simple GUI menu with 2X3 ImageButtons using PyQt4. It should look like this, except there should be images instead of text:

[image: There should be images instead of text]

I followed this tutorial: http://popdevelop.com/2010/05/an-example-on-how-to-make-qlabel-clickable/ 
for creating image buttons out of QLabels and I put them in grid layout.

It works fine, but my problem is that my application is supposed to be used using keyboard arrows (without mouse), so I want to make visible which label is focused before being selected.

Is it possible to do in PyQt? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of capturing keyboard events is done by installing an [event filter](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#installEventFilter) in your app with `installEventFilter ( QObject * filterObj )` and then filter with something like:

```
if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
    print "Key pressed!"
```